# Cannot find symbol Field when using Reflection API

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how to use reflection to print out the fields, methods, and constructors of a class. Here is the code in question:

```
static void displayMethodInfo(Object obj){
        Class c = obj.getClass();
        System.out.println(c + "{");
        int mods;
        Field fields[] = c.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Fields f : fields){
            if(!Modifier.isPrivate(f.getModifiers()))
                System.out.println("\t" + f);
        }
        Constructor [] constructors = c.getConstructors();
        for(Constructor con : constructors){
            System.out.println("\t" + con);
        }
        Method methods[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : methods){
            if(!Modifier.isPrivate(m.getModifiers()))
                System.out.println("\t" + m);
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
```

The error I am getting for Field is the same as the errors I am getting for Constructor and Method:

```
MethodInfoTest.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Field
location: class MethodInfoTest
                Field fields[] = c.getDeclaredFields();
                ^
MethodInfoTest.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Fields
location: class MethodInfoTest
                for(Fields f : fields){
```

I believe I am using the right API, I am using import java.lang.*; Which I believe contains what we need to use Field, Method, and Constructor. Is there something that I am misinformed about as to how we can use these types?

Comment: You also have a *typo* in your code, at line `for(Fields f : fields)`. It should be `Field`, instead of `Fields`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the star import does not import subpackages. `Field`, `Method`, and `Constructor` are members of **java.lang.reflect**.

Comment: Thank you, I was really looking for this. :3

Answer (score 3):

you should use:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper IDE in the future and press some keyword that calls "organize imports" and it will fix everything for you with imports.

Answer (score 0):

Use following import statements.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.Method;
```

Also, I think `Fields` is not a class in Reflection API.

My suggestion would be try using an IDE, it would suggest the possible compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
```

Consider using an IDE, for example Eclipse.